# NPM: cannot find module './lib' after upgrading to Node.js 5.0 on OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

### Background

I just upgraded from Node.js v4.1.1 to v5.0.0 on my Mac. I used the `node-v5.0.0.pkg` installer from the node website because I don't have `nvm` or `n` installed, and I didn't install through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/)).

### Problem

Now, every time I run `npm` I get the following error in my terminal:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I can't even re-install NPM through the traditional method of running `npm install -g npm` because the package manager itself doesn't work.

**How do I get NPM working again on my Mac?**

Comment: Note: this is a Q&A pair so others can benefit from what I've learned. But if anyone else has something to add, feel free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

1. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`
2. Reinstall node js v5.0.0

---

**Other notes:**
Looks like other people are running in to the same problem (see issue [#3606](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3606)). It sounds like a fix is in the works, so this issue will probably be resolved in the next release. In the interim, the only solution is to completely purge `npm` from your system and reinstall.